Why is there so much useless space on Spotfire's X-axis labels?
Using Spotfire analyst 14
I have two charts, both with the Y-axis being numeric, the X-axis is datetime. Both charts use the same data columns and stack on top of one another. The top chart is a line chart, the bottom a scatter of the same data.
I would like the line chart to also show the vertical labels on the X-axis.
When the chart sizes are nice, the X-axis labels do not show. When attempting to adjust the relative sizes of the charts by dragging the line between them - the line chart's X-axis label do not show - until suddenly they DO show, having a huge amount of unused space underneath them.
There appears to be no middle ground. Either no X-axis labels, or labels with a ton of useless space.
Can this be controlled? I.e. set the graph area itself to a given height and always show the X-axis labels?
Before attempting to alter size...

After dragging the separation line until the FIRST point at which the X-axis labels show...

